# Which plant is this? May a kind of grass?

Tags: identification

[image]

I bought this plant few months ago and lost the tag. Please help if you know what kind of plant it is. Also note that I have trimmed the leaves, it's not their natural shapes. They are spiky naturally.

Comment: Looks like  dracena Marginata or maybe belong to dracena Family . And definitely not a grass but a Tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Cordyline.  Probably Cordyline australis.   There are many forms that come in an array of colours.  You have a type of varigated Cordyline.   They are easy care.  They require lots of sunlight with minimal care.   Water it when the soil is dry.  Grow it indoors or out.  It can tolerate a frost, but not a hardy freeze.   It depends on the exact variety to give you the exact hardiness, but you would be safe in USDA Zone 10-12.  You maybe able to grow it outdoors in zone 9, but that is a big maybe.

[Variegated Cordyline](https://www.paramountplants.co.uk/plant/cordylinevar/cordyline-australis-variegated.html)

Comment: I just found out that Cordyline australis is usually pink but mine is not. Do you know why it could be the case? Is it good or bad? Mine is indoors.

Comment: There are many varieties of Cordyline australis variagata https://www.google.ca/search?safe=off&client=opera&hs=Jld&ei=IVI_Xu-GFMbJ-gS47oaAAQ&q=cordyline+australis+variegata&oq=cordyline+australis+variegata&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30j0i333.47086.50278..50594...1.3..0.85.596.9......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67.OFt3PPbr8yg&ved=0ahUKEwivm9SXm8PnAhXGpJ4KHTi3ARAQ4dUDCAo&uact=5 and many other varieties of don't have pink. The wild species does not have pink in it.  Pink has come about from intensive breeding programs.